# Where can I find Java Sun tutorials for download?

Tags: java

After a while, I went to [download.oracle.com](http://download.oracle.com) looking for Java 6 tutorials that were really great. I was surprised that I didn't found them there; where are they? If they are not hosted anymore by Oracle, can they be downloaded anywhere?

**Edit:** For some reason I can't open http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/. Can anyone provide direct link to current bundle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the [Java Tutorials page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) there's a link called "Download the latest Java SE Tutorials bundle" (in the right column). Follow it

Comment: 2 secs. darn. at least I was beaten by a fellow Austrian :-)

Comment: @Sean: isn't that what Arthur Seyß-Inquart said about Hitler?

Answer (score 0):

On the [tutorial main page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), in the **Tutorial Resources** box, click the **Download the latest Java SE Tutorials bundle** link

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/, right box "Tutorial Resources", link "Download the latest Java SE Tutorials Bundle".